# ES6 import module inside node execution script

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, importerror, package.json, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to execute a node script inside package.json which looks like this.

```
"parse-xlsx": "node ./services/orders-parsing/xlsx-parser executeXlsxParsing ./private/testdata/$FILENAME"
```

So when I run FILENAME=unfried-xlsx-2.xlsx npm run parse-xlsx for exemple, it executes this:

```
import XlsxParser from "./executeExcelParsing";

const executeXlsxParsing = () => {

   const xlsxParser = new XlsxParser({ fileName: process.argv.slice(2)[1] })

   xlsxParser.executeParsing()
}

export default executeXlsxParsing;
```

But when I do so, I got this error

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I did try to flag with `--input-type` but did not work and it outputs the same error than the one above:

```
"parse-xlsx": "node --input-type=module ./services/orders-parsing/xlsx-parser executeXlsxParsing ./private/testdata/$FILENAME"
```

For some reason I don't want to use `type=module` inside my `package.json` file.

Any workaround to be able to "force" the execution of this script with ES6 imports ?
Did try with latest LTS node 16.17.0 and my "old" version v12.22.1.

Thanks !

Comment: Sure @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans :)
Actually I just run FILENAME=unfried-xlsx-2.xlsx npm run parse-xlsx.

This is basically a node function and the FILENAME is an arg I catch inside this function.
As for --input-type I put it in a the script (npm run) not the command line.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans What do you mean by what I used ? Does something similar works with files ?
This is an imperative in my case, being to use a function inside a file that uses es6 imports.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did run  the following command: "FILENAME=unfried-xlsx-2.xlsx npm run parse-xlsx"  
                                                                                  
Which execute the following script: "node --input-type=module ./services/orders-parsing/xlsx-parser executeXlsxParsing ./private/testdata/$FILENAME".

Apologize If I was not clear enough.

Comment: You're right, done.

Answer (score 0):

`node --input-type` only tells node how to parse string input you're passing it:

```
> node --help
Usage: node [options] [ script.js ] [arguments]
       node inspect [options] [ script.js | host:port ] [arguments]

Options:
  ...

  --input-type=...      set module type for string input

  ...
```

However, you're telling it to run the file `./services/orders-parsing/xlsx-parser` so that won't work.

Your only option (until Node changes how `--input-type` works) is to have a package.json with the `type` property set to `module`. Thankfully, you canhave *lots* of package.json files, and `node` will simply use the one closest to the file it's being asked to run, so you can add a minimal `package.json` inside your `services/orders-parsing` dir, and then make sure that's set to `"type": "module"`, and now Node will run in ESM mode when asked to run files in the `services/orders-parsing` dir.

However, also note that if you want to pass arguments to `xlsx-parser`, you will need to use:

```
"parse-xlsx": "node ./services/orders-parsing/xlsx-parser -- executeXlsxParsing ./private/testdata/$FILENAME"
```

with those explicit `--` in there, because:

```
> node --help
Usage: node [options] [ script.js ] [arguments]
       node inspect [options] [ script.js | host:port ] [arguments]

Options:
  -                     script read from stdin (default if no file name is
                        provided, interactive mode if a tty)
  --                    indicate the end of node options
```

If you don't add those `--` then everything is considered options *for the node executable* instead of for whatever script you're running.

Comment: sounds like a clever solution.
This only thins, is that its causes some troubles recursively.
When you use type=module inside your package.json, you basically do have to replace all your import files and folders.

In the end its causes more harm than good by breaking and forcing me to change everything.
In your opinion, is there another way for execute a function without building the all nodejs app ? :)

Comment: why would you have to replace "all your import files"? that new package.json _only_ applies to node executing in that dir or its subdirs. Everything outside that filesystem subtree will use your regular package.json

Comment: Actually when I put some package.json inside the directory, recursively, all the folders/files used by my main function inside that dir need to be es5 modules if I use es5, or es6 if I use es6.
For example if I use es5 modules in that directory, I cannot use any other es6 files in that one even if coming at the root of the project

Comment: of course: don't mix CJS (not "es5", you're talking about code with `require` which is a node-invention as part of what node calls commonjs) with ESM in the same dirs. Those are very different module mechanisms, so put your CJS code somewhere, and your ESM code _somewhere else_ so that you can have one (or more) package.json files that tell node in which mode it needs to run.